# glutReshapeFunc и glutDisplayFunc в OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

Здравствуйте. Мне нужно уточнить полученную информацию с книги, ответьте на несколько вопросов, которые касаются `glutReshapeFunc` и `glutDisplayFunc` в OpenGL.

1. Насколько я понял с книги, в `glutDisplayFunc` проходит рисование / визуализация. В ней нужно размещать то, что нужно отрисовать в окне OpenGL?
2. "`glutReshapeFunc` вызывается при изменении размеров окна" — функция выполняет масштабирование в окне OpenGL, без неё все растягивается, а если указать её и реализовать, то можно этого избежать. Уточните, если что не так понял.

Вот такую реализацию `glutReshapeFunc` рекомендуют в книге:

```
void Reshape(GLsizei w, GLsizei h){
GLfloat aspectRatio; 

if (h == 0)
    h = 1;

glViewport(0,0,w,h);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
aspectRatio = (GLfloat)w / (GLfloat)h;

if (w <= h)
    glOrtho(100, -100, 100 / aspectRatio, -100 / aspectRatio, 100, -100);
else
    glOrtho(100 * aspectRatio, -100 * aspectRatio, 100, -100, 100, -100);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity(); }
```

Я не пойму зачем устанавливать `glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)` один раз, а потом менять на `glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)`. С остальным все ясно.

Comment: Вы будете задавать вопрос после каждой прочитанной страницы? Может сначал прочитаете всю книгу и примеры попробуете, а потом уже вопросы будете задавать?

Comment: Я задаю вопросы по тому, что не нашел. Если вам мягко говоря "лень" отвечать на мои простые вопросы, то не отвечайте. Я знаю что они "тупые" и простые, но хочу все же знать ответ.

Answer (score 3):

> glMatrixMode - Specifies which matrix stack is the target
>                       for subsequent matrix operations

`glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)` устанавливает проекционную матрицу, камеру так сказать, чтобы потом работать с `glOrtho()`, который в свою очередь создает параллельную проекцию и заменяет установленную матрицу, тем самым изображение в проекции принимает форму нового оконного режима. После необходимых изменений, `glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)` вновь устанавливает матрицу для работы с объектами и их трансформациями.

Это следует подчеркнуть, что все эти операции и пайплайн уже устарели и больше не должны использоваться. В современном OpenGL все операции должны проходить через `vertex shader` и `fragment shader`. Более подробную информацию можно получить [здесь](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Rendering_Pipeline_Overview).